# How to write the number of lines of an output in it's first line?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a line with the number of lines in the outputs I am generating with a loop for.

```
import os.path
import meshio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


cnt = 0
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".vtu"):
        mesh = meshio.read(file)
        Sn = mesh.point_data['Sn']
        coordinates = mesh.points
        data = np.zeros((len(coordinates), 4))
        data[:, :3] = coordinates
        data[:, 3:4] = Sn
        dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Sn'], dtype=float)
        dataframe["ID"] = dataframe.index
        del Sn, mesh, data, coordinates

        ####### Gas Saturation #####
        gas_saturation = dataframe[dataframe['Sn'] > 0]
        del gas_saturation['X']
        del gas_saturation['Y']
        del gas_saturation['Z']
        gas_saturation.name = 'Sn'

        n = gas_saturation['Sn'].count()
        print(n)


        gas_saturation.to_csv(f'D:/Bionapl_Nicolas/testKB/vtu_files/output_Sn/Sat_t{cnt}.txt', sep=" ",index = False, header = False)

        cnt += 1
```

The variable n gives the number of lines I am interested in, but I don't know how can I add n before the first line of the outputs.

If anyone has any other suggestions to make that happen or optimize the code above, plz tell me.

Comment: Try `len(gas_saturation)` instead

Comment: I tried         n = gas_saturation['Sn'].count()
and it did work. but still struggling to add it to the output files

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean by "adding n before the first line of the outputs". Your outputs are in CSV format, putting just the value of `n` as a first line will make problems for you as you try to read the file later. However it can be done. Just tell me if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I am trying to do. Put the value of n in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our discussion, a possible solution to your problem can be:

Replacing the following line:

```py
gas_saturation.to_csv(f'D:/Bionapl_Nicolas/testKB/vtu_files/output_Sn/Sat_t{cnt}.txt', sep=" ",index = False, header = False)
```

with

```py
with open(f'D:/Bionapl_Nicolas/testKB/vtu_files/output_Sn/Sat_t{cnt}.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(f'{n}\n')
    f.write(gas_saturation.to_csv(sep=" ", index=False, header=False))
```

However, you'll likely have problems when reading the files with `read_csv` function. A solution to this is to provide a value for the `skiprows` parameter, namely `skiprows=1` in your case since the value of `n` is in the first line.

Refer to the [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv) functions documentation for more information.

Comment: It does work exactly as I wanted. Thank you, appreciate it